# How do i get this 2 dimensional array to display as a table?

Tags: multidimensional-array

I need to make a table of seats with varying prices. Heres what i got so far. Im having trouble producing a table.

```
public class theatSeat {
public static final int rows=9;
public static final int cols=10;

public static void dispBox(int[][] a){
    for (int row=0;row<rows;row++){
        System.out.print((row+1)+" ");
        for (int col=0;col<cols;col++){
            System.out.print(a[row][col]+" ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}//Sets the diplayed seating box

public static void getPrice(int[][]a){
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int [] [] table = new int[rows] [cols];
    for(int row=0;row<rows;row++){
        for(int col=0;col<cols;col++){
            table[row][col]=0;
        }
    }
            dispBox(table);
```

}}//fin.

Comment: what do you mean you're having trouble producing the table? you mean it is not dispaying correctly? What output do you want, and what output are you getting? What method is not working correctly?

Comment: im trying to get something ordered in a table like

Comment: @user29442777 Check out my answer. It was a simple mistake you made in placing the `System.out.println()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you're making all the values 0. Did you want something like random value for each? Like this

```
Random random = new Random();
for(int row=0;row<rows;row++){
    for(int col=0;col<cols;col++){
        table[row][col]=random.nextInt(50);
    }
}
```

If you're having problems with displaying, try this

```
public static void dispBox(int[][] a){
    for (int row=0;row<rows;row++){
        System.out.print((row+1)+" ");

        for (int col=0;col<cols;col++){
            System.out.print(a[row][col]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        // this needs to go at the end of each line.
        // You were putting it at the end of each print
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't forget to accept answer if this solves your problem. Or feel free to ask some  questions.